# Question about horizontal scroll in CSS with <p> paragraphs html

Tags: html, css, scroll, paragraph

I'm learning web dev basics with HTML and CSS. I met an issue today : I want to make a horizontal scroll on my page with paragraphs (represented here by Lorem) inside but they appear in line while i want them in block.

Here's my code :

```css
.scroll {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.part {
    display: inline-block;
    align-content: flex-start;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="part">
    <p>
      Lorem...
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <p>
      Lorem...
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <p>
      Lorem...
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying tons of things but unsuccessful... (I think the first part is good)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.scroll { 
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

add this style..this will change the content flow to column wise

Comment: what is your expectation ? you wanted the items to be in each line right?

Comment: I want them to be in three blocks. You can scroll through these blocks horizontally.

Comment: Thank you for your time

Comment: add a height and give overflow : auto

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox provided a property called **flex-direction**. Which means that **what direction the flexbox children are laid out in** and by default this is set to **row**. [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox#columns_or_rows)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <p>Hello I'm Child 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <p>Hello I'm Child 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    <p>Hello I'm Child 3</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you see that in above example div is a block level element but they appear as inline becuase **flex-direction** is set to **row** by default. Now change the direction from **row** to **column** that will put flexbox children in a column layout.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    <p>Hello I'm Child 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <p>Hello I'm Child 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    <p>Hello I'm Child 3</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Hope that you understand the concept of flex-direction.